# Can I assign multiple data-id values to one attribute in one element?

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

I use WordPress. I have an audio player on my site. When a user clicks the play button on an individual song, it will play the song. The post ID is how the player determines which song to play.

So in the DIV that wraps the button tag, I assign an attribute: `data-id` which is the post id of the song. My app then grabs the MP3 file that is associated with that post ID. Simple.

My play button tag is essentially this:

```
<div class="item item-action" data-id="1161">
  <button class="btn-playpause"></button>
</div>
```

The important parts of my player.js file that handles the click event and plays the song is below:

**Simulate the play button**

```
// simulate the play btn
  $(document).on('click.btn', '.btn-playpause, .btn-queque', function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
      var self = $(this),
          item = $(this).closest('.item'),
          id = item.attr('data-id'),
          type = item.data('user-id') ? 'user' : 'post',
          play = true;

      if(!player){
        getItem(id, type).done(function(obj){
          if(obj.status == 'success'){
            mep.mepPlaylistTracks = obj.tracks;
            initPlayer();
            player && player.mepSelect(0, true);
          }
        });
        return;
      }

      if(self.is('.btn-queque')){
        play = false;
        self.parent().dropdown('toggle');
      }
      if( self.hasClass('is-playing') ){
        self.removeClass('is-playing');
        player.pause();
      }else{
        var index = player.find(id);
        if( index !== -1){
          var track = player.mepGetCurrentTrack();
          if(track && track.id == id && !play) return;
          player.mepSelect(index, true);
        }else{
          getItem(id, type).done(function(obj){
            if(obj.status == 'success'){
              addToPlay(obj.tracks, play);
            }
          });
        }
      }
  });
```

**getItem() function**

```
function getItem(id, type){
    return $.ajax({
       type : "post",
       dataType : "json",
       url : ajax.ajax_url,
       data : {action: "ajax_music", id : id, type: type, nonce: ajax.nonce}
    });
  }
```

**addToPlay() function**

```
function addToPlay(obj, play){
    if(obj.length == 1){
      player.mepAdd( obj[0], play );
    }else if(obj.length > 1){
      if(play){
        player.options.mepPlaylistTracks = obj;
        player.updatemepList();
        player.mepSelect(0, true);
      }else{
        for(var i=0; i<obj.length; i++){
          player.mepAdd( obj[i] );
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

You can see that once I click the play button, depending on a condition, it fires the `getItem()` function. getItem() takes the data-id attribute defined earlier as the `id` variable and begins to play the song.

The `addToPlay()` function will add another song to the playlist if there is already an instance of the player open. And when a user clicks another play button, it will add that new song to the list and begin to play that song.

### Is it possible to modify this code so that I can add multiple data-id values to my button code so that my script will recognize there is more than one song id and add those to my playlist, using the `addToPlay()` function?

I'd like to do something like this

```
<div class="item item-action" data-id="1161, 1288, 1456">
  <button class="btn-playpause"></button>
</div>
```

---

The reason I want to do this, is I would like to add a feature that will allow my users to Play All Songs on the current page they're viewing. Some of our pages, like the catalog page, displays dozens of songs that fit a certain criteria and I'd like the option to play all songs on the page.

Can anyone help push me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Just use something like `data-id="1161,1162,1163"` then use `.split(",")` to get an array of IDs.

Comment: Ok I'll see if I can work that in somehow. Thanks for the tip, Chris.

Answer (score 0):

You could store a JSON encoded array in the data-id tag. Like:

```
<div class="item item-action" data-id='[1161, 1288, 1456]'>
  <button class="btn-playpause"></button>
</div>
```

Then you can parse the array, and loop over its contents, adding each id to the queue.

See an example of parsing here: https://gist.github.com/charliepark/4266921

Comment: Aha, that sounds like the direction I need to go in. Thank you, I'll play around with this and report back.

Answer (score 0):

Here I present a alternative method.

In your markup, you can set the `data-id='[1234]` attribute as an encoded array.  You can then collect those properties and set them as the data id property on a given element using jQuery as I illustrate here:

```
let someElement = $('.item');
let setItems = someElement.data('id');
let thisItem = someElement.attr('data-id');
```

IMPORTANT: the `someElement.data('id')` returns the same as the `someElement.attr('data-id')` (except as a string) IF nothing for that element has been set with `someElement.data('id',[567,890]);` which sets the property `id` for `someElement`. So, once set that way

```
let x = someElement.data('id'); // returns the array 567,890
let org = someElement.attr('data-id'); // still returns the [1234]
```

This code illustrates:

```js
let someElement = $('.item').first();
let setItems = someElement.data('id');
let thisItemS = someElement.attr('data-id');
// make an array of the string
let thisItem = JSON.parse(thisItemS);
console.log(typeof setItems, setItems, typeof thisItemS, thisItemS, typeof thisItem, thisItem);
someElement.data('id', [567, 890]);
let x = someElement.data('id'); // returns and gets the array 567,890
let org = JSON.parse(someElement.attr('data-id')); // still returns the string [1234] made into an array
// merge with no duplicates, in the other code I used .map()
let z = Array.from(new Set(x.concat(org)));
console.log(x, org, z);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='item' data-id='[1234]'>me the item</div>
```

This code show a set of elements using the concepts introduced above plus:

- Set some check boxes for selection
- Get the values (all)
- Get the values (checkbox checked)

You can combine any of this for your original purpose, but you will need to manage that addition of new items values (and subsequently how to remove perhaps) on a given element.  You might even add to a `<select>` element so the user then can pick some to remove perhaps...

```js
function showPicks(choicedata) {
  let ul = $('#choices').append('<ul />');
  //ul.remove('li');
  ul.html('empty');
  ul.text('choices:');
  $.each(choicedata, function(index, choice) {
    let c = $('<li/>').html(choice);
    ul.append(c);
  });
}
$(function() {
  let mydata = $('.item').map(function() {
    return $(this).data('id');
  }).get();
  $('.all-items').data("id", mydata);
  showPicks(mydata); //now do what is desired
});

$('item.item-action').filter(':not(".some-items")')
  .on('click', '.btn-playpause', function() {
    let setItems = $(this).closest('.item').data('id');
    let thisItem = $(this).closest('.item').attr('data-id');
    // do what you wish here, I show them
    showPicks(setItems);
  });
$('.some-items').on('click', '.btn-playpause', function(event) {
  let mydata = $('.item-select').filter(':checked')
    .add(this) // set an additional one from the button
    .closest('.item')
    .map(function() {
      return $(this).data('id');
    }).get();
  $(event.delegatedTarget).data("id", mydata);
  let setItems = $(event.delegatedTarget).data('id');
  // the original pick
  let thisItem = $(event.delegatedTarget).attr('data-id');
  // do what you wish here
  showPicks(mydata);
});
```

```css
  .btn-playpause {
  height: 2em;
  )
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item item-action" data-id="[1161]">
  <button class="btn-playpause" type="button"></button>
  <input type="checkbox" class="item-select" />
</div>
<div class="item item-action" data-id="[1163]">
  <button class="btn-playpause"></button>
  <input type="checkbox" class="item-select" />
</div>
<div class="item item-action" data-id="[9961,7744]">
  <button class="btn-playpause" type="button"></button>
  <input type="checkbox" class="item-select" />
</div>
<div class="item item-action all-items" data-id="[42]">
  <button class="btn-playpause" type="button">Play All</button>
</div>
<div class="item item-action some-items" data-id="[95]">
  <button class="btn-playpause" type="button">Play selected</button>
</div>
<div id="choices">none</div>
```